# I am trying to execute PL/SQL block in shellscript. But while executing the script the out variable throws DB result along with Junk values

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, plsql, sqlplus

```
if [ $returncode -eq 0 ]

then

 query_msg=`$ISQL -S $USERNAME/$PASSWD@$SERVICENAME <<EOJ

        set serveroutput on;

        set heading off;

        set feedback off;

        set linesize 150;

declare

        out_value varchar2(32767);
BEGIN

        SELECT MESSAGE into out_value FROM RED.ERROR_LOG WHERE PROC = 'colour' and 

    to_char(to_date(DT,'DD-MON-YY')) = to_char(to_date(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY'));

dbms_output.put_line(out_value);

END;

/

EOJ`

        echo $query_msg > $DATADIR/colour_DB.log
```

in that log im getting query result along junk values ? i am missing something while declaring variable in plsql block? Can some help me on this?

query result : -

```
+query_msg=$'declare\n*\nERROR at line 1:\nORA-01403: no data found\nORA-06512: at line 5'
+ echo declare 0 1 221.log 132.log 321.log 456.log --> these are the files in the server path(unwanted result).
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the date reformatting. `TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YY')` is wrong. `SYSDATE` is already a date, not a VARCHAR2. What is the datatype of the column `DT`?

Comment: As an aside, it is silly to convert two DATEs to character strings just for comparison.  Instead of " to_char(to_date(DT,'DD-MON-YY')) = to_char(to_date(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY'));",   do trunc(DT) = trunc(sysdate).  Also, even if converting to strings, sysdate is already a DATE, so 'to_date(sysdate)' forces an implied to_char(), which may or may not behave as you expect. Same applies to your conversion of DT, if it is already a DATE type. And if it is _not_ a DATE type, that is a serious design flaw in your schema.

Answer (score 1):

In the shell, `*` expands to the list of files in the current directory, so `echo *` will produce the file list you are seeing.

The output from your PL/SQL block from SQL*Plus is something like:

```
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

Therefore `echo $query_msg` will print the word `declare` followed by the list of files in the current directory, followed by the rest of the message.

To prevent this, put it in soft-quotes:

```
echo "$query_msg"
```

or else use the SQL*Plus `spool` command to capture the original text in a file, which will also preserve the formatting.

Comment: Great answer that proves the worth of stackoverflow. It was a shell problem, not sqlplus or oracle! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce but cannot explain this issue.

A possible workaround is to replace  `echo $query_msg > $DATADIR/colour_DB.log` by a SPOOL command at the beginning of SQL statements:

```
SPOOL colour_DB.log
```

Answer (score 0):

The error `ORA-01403: no data found` is thrown because your query finds no data. You should catch it with something like:

```
DECLARE
  out_value varchar2(32767);
BEGIN
  SELECT MESSAGE into out_value 
   FROM RED.ERROR_LOG 
  WHERE PROC = 'colour' 
    AND to_char(to_date(DT,'DD-MON-YY')) = to_char(to_date(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY'));
  dbms_output.put_line(out_value);
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('Nothing found');
END;
```

EDIT: I think I understand now better what you want. I would use

```
query_msg=`$ISQL -s $USERNAME/$PASSWD@$SERVICENAME <<EOJ

SET HEADING OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET LINE 150

SELECT message
  FROM error_log
 WHERE proc = 'colour'
   AND dt BETWEEN TRUNC(sysdate) AND TRUNC(sysdate)+1
EOJ`
```

I haven't found a good way to show in SQL that no data is present (only in PL/SQL, but then spooling the output is more messy). So I'd suggest to handle this case in the bash script. Sadly my shell scripting is not good enough, but something like

```
if query_message is empty then query_message = 'No data found' fi
echo "$query_message"
```

Comment: The question here is why we have the list of files from the current directory in the shell variable. Oracle error messages are expected but list of files is not.

Comment: i tried doing the exception block but now query return more than one row . so i used cursor to the plsql block and more than one row is getting returned , Now my issue is wen no data found the query is returning nothing.

Comment: There is another exception TOO_MANY_ROWS for the case that the query returns more than one row.

Comment: I want to print the query result data rather than using TOO_MANY_ROWS exception.

Comment: I can show you, but I'll need to now the datatype of your column DT. Use `DESCRIBE RED.ERROR_LOG` or `SELECT * FROM all_tab_columns WHERE owner='RED' and table_name='ERROR_LOG`...

Comment: DT is date datatype . I want to print the data returned query wen data present and also wen data not present we need to print  no data is present